# How to shift elements in a 2D array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, puzzle, shift

So I am working on an 8puzzle slide game and I am having some trouble. So lets say that my current state S is:

1 5 6

3 7 B

2 8 4

where B represents the blank space (which is why I am doing my 2D array in String type). So I am trying to call move methods which will ultimately move the B space either up,down,left,or right. I have already recorded the position of B, so in this case it would be [1,2]. I use this B location to see if I can make a valid move up (can't make it if B[0] = 0), valid move down (can't make it if B[0] = 2), valid move left (can't make it if B[1] = 0) or valid move right (can't make it if B[1] = 2). So now if I do have a valid move for lets say up, how would I go about implementing that move function? I don't know how exactly to replace the location of B in my S state with the one above it if everything is in String type.

public class EightPuzzle {

```
String[][] gameBoard = new String[3][3];
String[] bLocation = new String[2];
String board;
String dir;

/*public void ReadFromTxt(String file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String read; 
    FileReader f = new FileReader(file);
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
    System.out.println("Loading puzzle from file...");
    while((read = b.readLine())!=null){
        if(read.length()==3){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                board[i][j] = (int)(read.charAt(j)-48);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    b.close();
    System.out.println("Puzzle loaded!");
}*/

public String[][] setState(String board){   
    gameBoard[0][0] = board.substring(0,1);
    gameBoard[0][1] = board.substring(1,2);
    gameBoard[0][2] = board.substring(2,3);
    gameBoard[1][0] = board.substring(4,5);
    gameBoard[1][1] = board.substring(5,6);
    gameBoard[1][2] = board.substring(6,7);
    gameBoard[2][0] = board.substring(8,9);
    gameBoard[2][1] = board.substring(9,10);
    gameBoard[2][2] = board.substring(10,11);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(gameBoard));

    return gameBoard;   
}

public String[][] randomizeState(){
    return null;
}

public void move(String dir){
    if(dir.equalsIgnoreCase("up")){
        if(bLocation[0].equals("0")){
            //cannot move up
        }
        else{
            int[] temp;

        }
    }
    if(dir.equalsIgnoreCase("down")){
        if(bLocation[0].equals("2")){
            //cannot move down
        }
        else{

        }

    }
    if(dir.equalsIgnoreCase("left")){
        if(bLocation[1].equals("0")){
            //cannot move left
        }
        else{

        }

    }
    if(dir.equalsIgnoreCase("right")){
        if(bLocation[1].equals("2")){
            //cannot move right
        }
        else{

        }
    }
}

public void bLocation(String board){
    setState(board);
    for(int i=0; i<gameBoard.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<gameBoard[i].length; j++){
            if(gameBoard[i][j].equals("b"))
            {
                bLocation[0] = Integer.toString(i);
                bLocation[1] = Integer.toString(j);
            }
        }
    }   
}

public static void main (String[]args){
    EightPuzzle b1=new EightPuzzle();
    b1.setState("156 37b 284");
    b1.bLocation("156 37b 284");

}
```

}

Comment: You could be using `char` instead of `String`.

Comment: Can you share snippet of the code you tried so far?

Comment: Are you asking how to swap the values of two variables? Swapping `S[0][2]` with `S[1][2]`?

Comment: I just added the code above. And yes basically I'm saying how would I 
1) replace B at the location it is to something higher 2 and
2) implement that into my current state S

Comment: The main problem comes with the fact that my B[1,2] for instance is not an int value, it is a String value, because all of my arrays/matricies are Strings due to the blank tile "b" in the initial state

Comment: I'm not sure why being a String value makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

A shift upwards would mean swapping `B` with the the tile above it.

For code simplicity, make a method `moveB` which swaps two locations:

```
private void moveB(int deltaRow, int deltaCol) {
    int newRow = bLocation[0] + deltaRow;
    int newCol = bLocation[1] + deltaCol;

    String temp = gameboard[newRow][newCol];
    gameBoard[newRow][newCol] = gameBoard[bLocation[0]][bLocation[1]];
    gameBoard[bLocation[0]][bLocation[1]] = temp;

    bLocation[0] = newRow;
    bLocation[1] = newCol;
}
```

To shift upwards: `moveB(-1, 0);`

To shift downwards: `moveB(1, 0);`

To shift left: `moveB(0, -1);`

To shift right: `moveB(0, 1);`